# EXCEL: Count values in column based on values in corresponding column

Tags: excel

I feel like this should be really easy, but I can't figure out the commands.

I have data in columns C and D which either contains a date or is blank.  I have data in column H which contains the name of an employee.  I want to calculate the total number of times, for each individual employee, non-blank values occur in C and non-blank values occur in D.

`CountIf` doesn't quite seem to have the capacity to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need `=COUNTIFS()`. Can you show the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to previos answer, if your criteria is for **non-blank** cells:

```
=COUNTIFS(H:H,"YourName",C:C,"<>"&"",D:D,"<>"&"")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later, use

```
=COUNTIFS(H:H,"YourName",C:C,"",D:D,"")
```